# Laravel 5.1 Database Seeder ReflectionException Class does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am currently trying to use a Seeder class file, called in the DatabaseSeeder::run method to seed the database using the latest version of Laravel (Laravel 5.1). However when I run the `db:seed` artisan method I get the following error and no new items are added to the database:

```
[ReflectionException]
Class PostsSeeder does not exist
```

The source of the DatabaseSeeder.php file is as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call(PostsSeeder::class);

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

And the source of the PostsSeeder.php file is:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PostsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Post::class, 25)->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you refresh your autoload files so that Laravel can find your class (``composer dump-autoload``)?

Comment: you need to use PostsSeeder in top of the class,before call PostsSeeder

Comment: @ImtiazPabel both classes are in the same namespace, so no need for "use" statement

Comment: Available seeder classes are taken from cached autoloder. Reload the cache as @ErikJohansson suggests and it will work.

Comment: Like others have said you need to `composer du` but there's a more in depth answer described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36207261/5056424