# Class 'UserTableSeeder' does not exist - Laravel 5.0 [php artisan db:seed]

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying a basic php artisan db:seed after migrating my database but it keeps returning the title error in cmd -[ReflectionException] Class 'UserTableSeeder' does not exist

Things I Have Tried

- Change the namespace of the 'UserTableSeeder.php' File 'namespace Database\seeds;' and 'use Database\seeds\UserTableSeeder;' in the 'DatabaseSeeder.php' File

Below is the migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('password', 60);
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Below is the UserTableSeeder.php

```
<?php
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(['email' => 'foo@bar.com']);
    }
}
```

Below is the DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to import this (UserTableSeeder) class?

Answer (score 143):

Run `composer dumpautoload` after creating files in the database/ folder.

**Why?**

Check the `composer.json` autoload section and you'll see the `database/` folder is loaded by "classmap" ([source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.0.22/composer.json#L14)):

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

The Composer [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) describe classmap as:

> The classmap references are all combined, during install/update, into
>   a single key => value array which may be found in the generated file
>   vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php. **This map is built by scanning
>   for classes in all .php and .inc files in the given directories/files**.
>
> You can use the classmap generation support to define autoloading for
>   all libraries that do not follow PSR-0/4. To configure this you
>   specify all directories or files to search for classes.

Emphasis added. You need to run the `composer dumpautoload` command to generate a new classmap every time you add a file to `database/`, otherwise it will not be autoloaded.

The `app/` folder, by contrast, uses the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard for converting a fully qualified class name to a filesystem path. This is why you don't need to `dumpautoload` after adding files there.

Comment: I added two other seed files and they ran fine. The third one got 'stuck'. I spent a half hour trying to figure out what I did wrong. Your solution worked like a charm. Not in love with the laravel developers right now, but I am in love with you! ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Added a folder under app/ for more organized structure and needed to update composer.json to map. This worked for me :)

Comment: This is helpful, but the best solution is not to run `composer dumpautoload`. If you add `"Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeds/"` in the `psr-4` section, and remove its entry from the `classmap` section, then everything just works as expected, with no need to run extra commands when you add a new class.

Answer (score 33):

**Sometimes the code is correct but** you need to run the following command in order to run the seeder command.
First Run this command

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Then seed the seeder

```
php artisan db:seed --class=CreateUsersTable
```

I hope it will work

Comment: composer dump-autoload did the trick for me after switching branches with diffrent talbe seeders

Comment: composer dump-autoload    and     composer dumpautoload  works in same way

Answer (score 29):

Try changing

```
  $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
```

to

```
  $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
```

and try running

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 24):

When we change or delete the Controller file or another file then their file should be removed from everywhere in code. You need to run command to refresh your composer

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

Add namespace in your class.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;
...
```

run composer dump-autoload after that