# Seeder already exists : Class LaravelSeeder does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

When the seeder is created by system A with command:

`php artisan make:seeder LaravelSeeder`

Then you can seed that seeder easily in system A with command:

`php artisan db:seed --class=LaravelSeeder`

But when the same seeder will be pushed and pulled in system B. Then it should not create again. And should be run directly with:

`php artisan db:seed --class=LaravelSeeder`.

But when I run this command it says

> Class LaravelSeeder does not exist

So I again create the same seeder with command `php artisan make:seeder LaravelSeeder`.

Even after running this command it says Seeder already exists!.

- Why the Laravel seeder behave like that?
- Any solution to prevent from this?

Comment: Run `composer dump autoload` and try again. And try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206742/class-usertableseeder-does-not-exist-laravel-5-0-php-artisan-dbseed?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: this command will update the auto load file right ? And autoload file will not be pushed. 
So do i will have to run this command every time when i will get new seeder ?